# Set variable by running a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and it's workings. I am wanting to simply create a variable called 'code' and fill this variable with the method i have made.

Here is the code

```
codeLength = 4
code = GenerateCode()
print(code)

def GenerateCode(code):
    symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    random.shuffle(symbols)
    del symbols[(symbols.count - codeLength)]
    code = symbols
    return code
```

So the method should pick 4 letters from the array symbols be randomising it then removing 2. I want the letters at the end to be the variable 'code'

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is the question? You can't just assign code to `GenerateCode()` without declaring `GenerateCode()` beforehand

Comment: I think you may have to pass codeLength to the function and not code

Comment: @SmitM that's another good point. Alternatively you could use a `global`

Comment: The biggest problem with your code as posted is that `symbols.count`. `list.count` is a method, which takes a value and counts how many times that value appears. You can't subtract a number from a method. You probably wanted `len(symbols)`. If you're coming to Python from a different language, how to get the length of a container is one of those things that's different in every language for no good reason…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the main errors with your code.

- You call a function before defining it;
- You delete a single character out of your list, but it would be better to slice it;
- `codeLength` would be better passed as an argument.

Here is an example fixing those issues.

```
import random

def gen_code(length, symbols='ABCDEF'):
    code = random.sample(symbols, length)
    return str(code)

code = gen_code(4)
```

As an improvement, notice how setting `symbols` as a keyword argument allows to keep a default value but change the character if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to Python but have experience with C# [Unity] and in C# it doesn't matter when the method is declared.

I have followed these steps but it uses the same symbol twice sometimes. Thats why originally i removed X amount of letters from the list as i didnt want repeated letters

Comment: If you do not want repeated letters, you want to use `random.sample` then

Comment: If that answer was helpful, you can mark it as accepted! This will help future users find useful answers. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow then! You can click on the check mark at the left of the answer

Comment: Got it. Thanks!